# Session flashdata doesn´t work on form submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the ion-auth "library" for codeigniter (https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) and I am getting a trouble with the flashdata. This is a sumary of code:

```
public function reset_password($code = NULL)
{
    if (!$code)show_404();
    $this->user = $this->ion_auth->forgotten_password_check($code);
    if ($this->user)
    {
        //setting the rules
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            //more code
            $this->_get_csrf_nonce();
            /*
              One of the things this function (_get_csrf_nonce) makes is:
              $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfkey', $key);
              $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfvalue', $value); 
            */
            //The next thing is load the view with the form
        }
        else //form is running
        {
            echo "flashdata csrfkeyvalue: ".$this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue')."<br>";
            die;
            //more code, but not important by the moment
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the echo of $this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue') when the form is submited allways show nothing.
If I make something like:

```
private function _get_csrf_nonce(){
    /*$this->load->helper('string');
    $key   = random_string('alnum', 8);
    $value = random_string('alnum', 20);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfkey', $key);*/
    $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfvalue', $value);
    redirect(base_url("auth/test"));
    //return array($key => $value);
}
public function test()
{
    echo "flashdata csrfkeyvalue: ".$this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue')."<br>";
}
```

In this case... it works. The view I am using to the form is very very similar from this: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/views/auth/reset_password.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

After fighting a little, I was looking for something that could make a new request between the view of form was loaded and the form was submited... finally, I discover (I didn´t remember) a javascript that is request though a controller (to translate some texts, based on this tutorial: http://www.student.kuleuven.be/~r0304874/blog/international-javascript-files-in-codeigniter.html). I was loaded in this way:

```
<script src="<?=site_url('jsloader/login.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks.